# How to break a while loop without breaking the rest of the program in java?

Tags: java, while-loop, average, break

I'm a beginner at java and I'm trying to break a while loop without breaking the entire program. My program entails me to accept any number of grades from the user, but to stop at any number they want. For example, the user can say they have 40 students, but only want to enter in grades for 5 of them.

When I entered in the break statement, the mean (average), median, and mode(most occurring element) are not displaying the right numbers. How can I make it so that the break statement doesn't break the rest of the program?

I understand that it can be done with a for loop, but the use of a while loop is a requirement in the program.

Comment: The rest of your program assumes that there are `grades.length` students.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `ArrayList` instead of `array`?

Comment: I have to use an array.

Answer (score 2):

You declare `grades` to be the maximum number of students.

If the user decides to exit early, then all your following logic needs to be based on how many students they actually entered, rather than how many they could have entered.

So you need to change your code to:-

- have a variable which is how many grades have actually been entered
- use this instead of `grades.length`
- use this variable to limit how much of the grades array you process in following loops, etc.